# OpenCV - Library not loaded error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/tensorboy/pytorch_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation) for image/video processing. I am using Python 2.7 on OS X. I already have a virtual environment working, and I used to be able to import `cv2` and run code without any problems. While I was running this tutorial, I ran into this problem:

```
File "convert.py", line 10, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/angelovillasanta/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-6fe1898/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.2.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

Now I'm not sure what to do or how to resolve this. I seem to be missing the jpeg library but when I run `brew install jpeg`, the console tells me it's already installed.

Comment: Have you tried running `brew install libjpeg`?

Comment: **homebrew** will have installed `libjpeg` at `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib` whereas your Python is looking for `/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib`. Sorry I don't know enough about Python to tell you how to tell Python to look somewhere else.

Comment: @jpyams yes I did. running it again says that `jpeg 9b is already installed`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

try symlinking it from $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib

Found here and it worked for me
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/323